# Rails Installing Dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I just downloaded a Rails application that I'm trying to run on my computer. I'm running OS X 10.8.

I ran `gem install rails` which installed rails. I then ran `bundle install` in the project and it keeps quitting saying: `Abort Trap: 6`.

I then ran `rails server` and apparently `rake` was missing. So I ran `gem install rake`. Now, when I run `rails server`, I get that `activesupport-3.2.9` is missing. I ran `gem install activesupport`, but that installed `activesupport-3.2.11` and so 3.2.9 is still missing. I tried running `gem install activesupport-3.2.9` but it says it cannot find that version.

Why is this such a mess? I think I'm doing it wrong. How can I install all dependencies at once and fix my issue?

`bundle install` error:

```
185 /Users/nayef/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb
  186 /Users/nayef/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0/fcntl.bundle
  187 /Users/nayef/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/ssl-internal.rb
  188 /Users/nayef/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/x509-internal.rb
  189 /Users/nayef/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl.rb
  190 /Users/nayef/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

`rails` error:

```
/Users/nayef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `block in materialize': Could not find activesupport-3.2.9 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from /Users/nayef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `map!'
        from /Users/nayef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `materialize'
        from /Users/nayef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
        from /Users/nayef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb:27:in `specs'
        from /Users/nayef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:41:in `candidate?'
        from /Users/nayef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:60:in `setup'
        from /Users/nayef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/nayef/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
        from /Users/nayef/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
        from /Users/nayef/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from /Users/nayef/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Run `bundle install` again and paste the complete error message please.

Comment: @gmalette its just an Abort Trap 6. See above, I copied and pasted it.

Comment: @gmalette Just added the error message when running `rails`

Comment: Since you're using RVM, you should update your version of Ruby:

`rvm upgrade 1.9.3-p194 1.9.3-p362`

Comment: Whoops, I'm out of date. The correct command: `rvm upgrade 1.9.3-p194 1.9.3-p374`

Comment: @TimDorr Thanks but that's not an answer to this issue.

Comment: @Darksky It seems like the openssl package  you have is creating the problem. AFAIK you can simply change `https` to `http` in your gemfile source (`http://rubygems.org`) OR you can reinstall RVM Ruby after installing the OpenSSL package (check https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates/issues/38)

Comment: @gmalette nice works. I already have OpenSSL though. Is it okay to just run without `https`? I looked at the solution and it looks bug-prone. I don't want to break rails again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `http` instead of `https` in your gemfile source (`http://rubygems.org`)

Using `http` is not a problem in itself, but it does make your application more vulnerable to certain attacks. Someone could impersonate `http://rubygems.org` and serve you a modified gem. I've never heard of such attacks, but they are in theory possible.